# Cannot `/GET` Node JS

Tags: node.js

Project is hosted on this [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/rosantoz/node-mongo-chat). I'm getting cannot GET error when I run localhost:8088. What could be wrong? One of the things that I see missing is something like `use(static(__dirname + '/public'));` I've also attached an image of the project structure.

```
 var express = require('express')
        , app = express()
        , http = require('http')
        , server = http.createServer(app)
        , io = require('socket.io').listen(server)
        , messageModel = require('./messageModel')
        , clients = [];

    io.sockets.on('connection', function (client) {

        messageModel.message.find().limit(10).sort({_id: -1}).exec(function (err, results) {
            results.reverse();
            results.forEach(function (message) {
                client.emit('addMessage', message.nickname, message);
            });
        });

        client.on('join', function (name) {

            clients.push(name);
            clients.sort();
            client.emit('usersConnected', clients);

            client.set('nickname', name);
            client.broadcast.emit('addUser', name);

        });

        client.on('newMessage', function (message) {
            client.get('nickname', function (error, nickname) {
                client.broadcast.emit('addMessage', nickname, message);
                client.emit('addMessage', nickname, message);
                messageModel.message.create({
                    nickname: nickname,
                    message : message.message,
                    date    : message.date
                }, function (err, rs) {
                    console.log(err);
                });
            });
        });

        client.on('removeUser', function () {
            client.get('nickname', function (error, nickname) {
                client.broadcast.emit('removeUser', nickname);
                client.emit('removeUser', nickname);
            });
        });

        client.on('disconnect', function () {

            client.get('nickname', function (error, nickname) {
                clients.splice(clients.indexOf(nickname), 1);
                client.broadcast.emit('removeUser', nickname);
                client.emit('removeUser', nickname);
            });

        });

        client.on('userEvent', function (message) {
            messageModel.message.create({
                nickname: '',
                message : message.message,
                date    : message.date
            }, function (err, rs) {
                console.log(err);
            });
        });

    });

    server.listen(8088);
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You don't have any routing logic. https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

Comment: Correct. I added a public directory and created a routing logic. Problem fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```